# How to submit PHP Same Page without jumping (No Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a code that would submit at the same page however it jumps at the top. I would like to have it stay at the same position.

```
<?php

<form name="myform" action="#" method="POST">
  <input name="myform" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['myform'])){ 
    var_dump($_POST);
  }
?>
```

?>

Comment: Since you've added restrictions like "no ajax", it really helps if you explain _why_ since it sounds like it would be perfect for this.

Comment: PHP is server side, so the page has to be refreshed to access the variables posted by a form unless you use something like Ajax. I don't know how you would do this without Ajax, because you'd have to know the position to scroll the page to after the form is submitted. And to do that, you'd probably need Javascript anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to jump to a particular place on the page create an anchor there:

```html
<a id="myanchor"></a>
```

and in the action of the form add it:

```html
<form name="myform" action="#myanchor" method="POST">
```

This will cause the page to jump to the anchor after the refresh.

You can limit a bit the overall effect of page refresh by placing everything in an `<iframe>` BUT that generally looks bad: like very bad development.

**A little bit of a compromise would be to place only the form in an iframe**: then submit will refresh only that iframe while the rest of the page remains intact.

In fact an XHR (Ajax) would be the best thing to do here as it would allow you to refresh only the actual part of the page which you want to refresh.

Comment: Isn't it `<a name="myanchor">` rather than "id"? Or can you use either? It's ages since I've messed with this, but I always used "name".

Comment: `id` is correct, but true, it tends to be confusing. More details: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html

Comment: You also don't need a `<a>` at all. Just point to any ID within the page. It usually makes a lot more sense to have them on header (`<h*>`) tags.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so your page is always going to reload what you should looking for is how to move to a certain section of your web page as the page reloads.

Comment: i know it would reload, was referring to not jump